# Usage of If exists with dynamic sql in stored procedure

Tags: sybase

In Sybase, how do I use an `if exists` clause with dynamic SQL formed in a stored procedure?

The stored procedure has many `if` conditions so I am trying to create
dynamic sql to simplify the code.

e.g.

```
declare @sqlquery varchar(500)
set @sqlquery = "select * from books where book = 10"
if exists(@sqlquery)
begin
   exec("select book_id,book from books here book = 10")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply as follows (ignoring the fact that @sqlquery is not appearing in the IF-block):

```
IF @sqlquery IS NOT NULL -- or whatever condition you want to use
BEGIN
   EXEC('...')
END
```